# Is there any way to write an object to amazon s3 with OutputStream in SDK for java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I would like to write a serializable object into a bucket of amazon s3. However I cannot find a class called S3ObjectOutputStream even though I can use S3ObjectInputStream.

Of course I can write the serializable object to a local directory and then upload the file onto s3, but I am just wondering is there any way to write to amazon s3 with OutputStream directly?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64508183/1704634 for a solution. The S3OutputStream wraps an S3 cilent, and automatically supports multipart transfer if the stream size becomes too large.

Answer (score -2):

I use this function:

```
public String upload(String name, InputStream is, String contentType) throws FileLoadException {

    try {

        log.debug("Loading file {} into S3 Bucket {}", name, bucketName);
        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();

        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentType(contentType);
        objectMetadata.setCacheControl("public, max-age=31536000");

        String filename = String.format("%s/%s", s3Folder, name);

        amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, filename, is, objectMetadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

        log.debug("Image {} upload into  S3 Bucket {}", name, bucketName);
        return s3BaseUrl + filename;
    } catch (Exception e) {
       //handle
    }
}
```

I added this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.194</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score -3):

How about using the PutObjectRequest?
Take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-

which allows public PutObjectRequest(String bucketName,
                        String key,
                        InputStream input,
                        ObjectMetadata metadata)

Comment: This takes an InputStream, which is not at all what the question requires.