# How to create a java OutputStream for an S3 object and write value to it?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3, outputstream

Existing ways of adding content to an S3 file using methods in AmazonS3 class are

- by putObject with an InputStream
- Creating a local file with content and uploading it to S3.

Is there a way an OutputStream can be created for an existing S3 object to which values from a list can be written into? I see there are no APIs for doing so.

Comment: An OutputStream is used for reading data from a source and an InputStream is used for writing data to a target. What you're trying to do does not make sense. Use the InputStream.

Comment: @Trinopot the OutputStream has `write` methods, that's what you use (indirectly) when you use  `System.out.println()` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html

Comment: Oh yeah. Guess I got it inverted.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to create an S3OutputStream which wraps the AmazonS3 client. See this gist for the implementation:
https://gist.github.com/blagerweij/ad1dbb7ee2fff8bcffd372815ad310eb
It automatically detects large files, and uses multi-part transfers when required. It uses a byte-array for buffering, the size of that buffer depends on your use case. (default is 10MB)

For example:

```
   final S3Client s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
   final OutputStream out = new S3OutputStream(s3Client, "bucket", "path/file.ext");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at AWS SDK [Performing Operations on an Amazon S3 Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object)

```
...
S3Client s3;
...
// Put Object
s3.putObject(bucket,object);
```

Comment: Problem here is, the object i am trying to put here could be much bigger may be in gbs of size. Heap memory may take a hit in such a scenario.

Comment: Doesn't the  "Upload Objects in Multiple Parts" section helps in that situation?